# A searchable database of articles

Tags: note-taking, information-management

I frequently look up tutorials and find a really useful one after a bit of searching. However, after a while I forget and have to look for these tutorials again, sometimes unsuccessfully.

Is there a way to store these articles in a database that is searchable by keywords, tags, categories? Ideally, I would be able to search for a topic, then a list of relevant articles would appear along with my personal notes about how this article is useful.

It'd be especially useful if there's a cross-platform, cloud-based solution.

Comment: If it’s a Web app, self-hosted or hosted? If it’s not a Web app: for which OS? (or do you want to require it to be a Web app?)

Comment: Using a browser bookmark is not an option?

Comment: Web-app can be either self-hosted or hosted. Desktop app should be cross-platform (Linux, Mac, Win). Browser bookmark is good for web link, but sometimes I want to mention book chapters and add my own review. Plus, I want to store the article's text itself just in case the links go cold.

Comment: Hm, so some kind of bookmarks which would store the webpage itself along and allow you to put annotations/markers in would fit? If so, and you're using Firefox, maybe the [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/) addon is worth a look.

Comment: I already thought of Evernote with each article being a note in a notebook. It fulfills all requirements above, the only problem is that I don't know how locked-in I am. I really like the idea of owning my data to be backed up and shared.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of using [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/) (acquired by Mozilla so we kinda know it will stick around)? I used it for a while and it does quite a decent job:

- lets you save links,
- lets you tag them by categories,
- lets you search your tags,
- all of the above for free,
- if you are ready to pay for a premium version ($5/month), it will keep a personal backup of all the articles and web pages you save.

**BUT**

- *there's no note or summary field for inputting one's own remarks.
  It all depends on how critical the note taking function is for you.*

I had a similar issue a while ago, where I wanted to keep track of books/articles I read with my own notes (keeping notes makes me feel like I retain the information better). And, I solved it by making an app on Simitless. I made an [Articles Database](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-articles-database) template from it, if you want to either copy or inspire from it to make your own.

For articles, I usually

- input the URL,
- a short summary of why I thought it was interesting at the time,
- assign some tags,
- assign categories and topics,
- for the full content, depending on the source, I would either copy/paste the text,
- or print the page to PDF with Chrome and upload it as a file to the app. I haven't found a solution that lets me grab the content automatically yet,
- in addition, you can import your list of articles (if you have one) and you can always export your database,
- (it is a web app, so OS independent).

For sources that I trust will remain online (Instructables, Khan Academy, etc.), I tend not to save the content as I assume it will be there later.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the team that made Simitless so my opinion might be biased.**